# How 'Set Default value' to 'NOW()' with Sequel PRO?

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I have a MySQL table with some dates,
I need that one of them have a default value equal to current time,
I'm using 'Sequel Pro' to build the database,
Then i wrote 'now()' (and 'GETDATE()') in default value, but doesn't work.

Can someone do help me, How 'Set Default value' to 'NOW()' with Sequel PRO?

ERROR:

> An error occurred when trying to change the field 'DataDoPedido' via
>
> ALTER TABLE `Reserva` CHANGE `DataDoPedido` `DataDoPedido` DATE
>    NOT NULL
>    DEFAULT 'now()'
>
> MySQL said: Invalid default value for 'DataDoPedido'

thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that support for using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as `DEFAULT` is for MySQL 5.6.x +

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For MySQL, the `DEFAULT` specified for a column must be a constant; it cannot be the return from a function. The one exception to this is the `TIMESTAMP` datatype, which can have a `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

If you need to initialize a `DATE` column, one workaround is to create a `BEFORE INSERT ON` trigger.

Comment: Thanks.
Can i use TIMESTAMP like DATE in PHP?

I changed DATE to TIMESTAMP on database and worked, but i never used TIMESTAMP, what is the difference to 'date'?

Comment: The `DATE` datatype in MySQL has no time portion, it's only year-month-day, so when that gets cast to a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, the time component is considered to be midnight 00:00:00. The `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` datatypes hold date AND time with resolution down to a second. With the MySQL JDBC driver, the DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP are basically interchangeable. Not sure about PHP.